# setting z-index in javascript: null error

Tags: javascript, css, z-index

I have a series of images laid on top of one another.  I intend to bring one to the front and animate its opacity.  I am using the following code:

```
document.getElementById('newFrame').style.zIndex="10";
```

Having set the id in the following way:

```
var newFrame = "p" + rand;
```

(rand is a random number, and the image id's are p1, p2 etc)

But I'm getting the error `"Cannot read property 'style' of 'null'"`

and despite multiple changes I can not get this to work - please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

newFrame is an object and so you need to reference it like one.You need to do something like this:

```
document.getElementById(newFrame).style.zIndex="10";
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simply, you aren't using the variable you've set, you're using a string instead.

Your code is looking for an element with the ID of 'newFrame' rather than an ID 'p'+rand()